# Neo4j returns HTTP 400

Tags: c#, database, azure, neo4j, syntax-error

I'm a co-founder of a service called Endorphin that uses neo4j to store social graph data. We have an issue with it.

We thought that improving the query will resolve the issue but as it turns out this is not the reason of DB failure because sometimes it returns successfully and sometimes fails with `SyntaxException`. We cant see the reason that makes this happen. Sending queries through API results in unsystematic failure of queries whereas when we send same queries using console they work perfectly well.

Details:

The Neo4j version is 1.9.2

We're using Windows Azure, OS Ubuntu 12.04LTS, running in JDK7

System configuration is AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 4171 HE 8 core cpu, memory 14GB, HDD 250 GB + 1TB, the database size is 1GB.

Cache config is the following:

```
cache_type=gcr 
use_memory_mapped_buffers=true 
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=1024M 
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=1024M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=2048M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1024M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=1024M
```

I've attached an example of the query and error:

The query was:

```
start n=node(1341474), oldFriend0 = node(21103), 
      oldFriend1 = node(21103), oldFriend2 = node(302) 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635082180250000000}]-oldFriend0 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635082713870000000}]-oldFriend1 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635082527270000000}]-oldFriend2 
return 1.0 as Val
```

The response status was: 400 Bad Request

The response from Neo4j (which might include useful detail!) was:

```
{"message" : "Can't create UNNAMED1 with properties here. 
It already exists in this context", "exception" : "SyntaxException", "fullname" : "org.neo4j.cypher.SyntaxException", "stacktrace" : 
[ "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$anonfun$assertNothingIsCreatedWhenItShouldNot$1.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:83)", 
"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$anonfun$assertNothingIsCreatedWhenItShouldNot$1.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:82)", 
"scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:547)", 
"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.assertNothingIsCreatedWhenItShouldNot(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala
```

One more example:

The query was:

```
start n=node(1398749), oldFriend0 = node(6856), oldFriend1 = node(6856), 
oldFriend2 = node(6848), oldFriend3 = node(6848), oldFriend4 = node(6848), 
oldFriend5 = node(5600), oldFriend6 = node(7245), oldFriend7 = node(223), 
oldFriend8 = node(223), oldFriend9 = node(223), oldFriend10 = node(223), 
oldFriend11 = node(223), oldFriend12 = node(223), oldFriend13 = node(223), 
oldFriend14 = node(223), oldFriend15 = node(7821), oldFriend16 = node(126899), 
oldFriend17 = node(7133), oldFriend18 = node(7133), oldFriend19 = node(6844), 
oldFriend20 = node(6915) create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094700950000000}]-oldFriend0 create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094783870000000}]-oldFriend1 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094735780000000}]-oldFriend2 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094744040000000}]-oldFriend3 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094744310000000}]-oldFriend4 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094776820000000}]-oldFriend5 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094730830000000}]-oldFriend6 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094731200000000}]-oldFriend7 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094742500000000}]-oldFriend8 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094742990000000}]-oldFriend9 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094743440000000}]-oldFriend10 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094743840000000}]-oldFriend11 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094744640000000}]-oldFriend12 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094749740000000}]-oldFriend13 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094826130000000}]-oldFriend14 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094748250000000}]-oldFriend15 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094708340000000}]-oldFriend16 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094742320000000}]-oldFriend17 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094742770000000}]-oldFriend18 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094692580000000}]-oldFriend19 
create unique n<-[:Comment{CreatedTime:635094743430000000}]-oldFriend20 
return 1.0 as Val
```

The response status was: 400 Bad Request

```
The response from Neo4j (which might include useful detail!) was: 
{ "message" : "Can't create UNNAMED1 with properties here. 
It already exists in this context", "exception" : "SyntaxException", 
"fullname" : "org.neo4j.cypher.SyntaxException", 
"stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$anonfun$assertNothingIsCreatedWhenItShouldNot$1.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:83)",
 "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$anonfun$assertNothingIsCreatedWhenItShouldNot$1.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:82)", 
"scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:547)"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**UPD**: We're using Neo4jClient for C# to execute the queries. They don't fail via console, but they randomly fail when executed with this driver.

Comment: Regarding system spec: Since you're using Windows Azure, it's probably more helpful to simply say you're using an XL (8-core) virtual machine (and might want to include OS image version). Including CPU isn't needed, as that's not part of the machine sizing spec.

Comment: Can you somehow reproduce it?

Do you use a driver? Or do you execute the query directly via the REST API ?

Tried it and couldn't reproduce.

Would it be possible to share the database that you use for it?

I would also recommend to start using parameters instead of literal values for the node-id's and creation-timestamps so that the Cypher query cache could be leveraged.

Comment: Hello, @MichaelHunger, the query works well when executed via console, but it fails randomly when we execute it with a driver for C#, Neo4jClient (v 1.0.0.572)

Comment: @MichaelHunger we can share the database with you, how can we reach you?

Comment: Send it to *michael at neo4j.org* possibly a drobox or microsoft sync link. Together with your server config files. Are there any proxies, firewalls or other network infrastructure in between that does caching or other things?

Comment: thanks, I've sent you the dropbox link

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab at something that might help.

Have you tried sending as a batch of separate statements?
See: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html

This way you could parameterize it and just send them all at once:

```
start n=node({destId}), oldFriend=node({oldFriend})
create unique n<-[:Comment {relProps}]-oldFriend
```

And in the params use:

```
{CreatedTime:635094700950000000}
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference there's this issue that will track progress/findings for this issue: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1040